# Creating a list of inputs using createElement()

Tags: javascript, createelement

How would I create a list of the user's inputs using `createElement()`?
Something so that when somebody adds text into the `prompt("enter text")` box, it displays on the screen. I've tried researching `createElement()`, but I'm still only able to display the latest input using a variable.

Edit:

```
<script>

function myFunction()
{
var user =prompt("Enter your name:")
var text =prompt("Hello " + user + ". Enter some text:")
count++;
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML=count;
document.getElementById("latest").innerHTML=text;
}

</script>

<p>Total: <span id="count">0</span></p>
<p>Latest blocked term: <span id="latest"></span></p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>
```

I've cut off unrelated parts, so I hope this works.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing that works, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here.

## The DOM way

This is the way that you are searching for with `createElement`. It is the best way in a sense, because it allows you to interact with the DOM as it already exists. You don't however *need* `createElement`: you should really use [`createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createTextNode), which does what it says on the tin:

```
function myFunction() {
    var name = prompt("Enter some text:"),
        node = document.createTextNode(name);
    document.getElementById('latest').appendChild(node);
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ySJD/)

(This results in adding the text to the end of the element: it does not remove the content that is already there.)

## The realistic way

While using the DOM functions is all well and good, it is not really idiomatic Javascript. In reality, `innerHTML` is the property you should probably be using. Browsers are *really* good at parsing HTML (it's what they're built for, after all!) so this will almost certainly be quicker than the DOM method.

```
function myFunction() {
    var name = prompt("Enter some text:");
    document.getElementById('latest').innerHTML = name; // to overwrite the existing contents
    document.getElementById('latest').innerHTML += name; // to add to the existing contents
}
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ySJD/1/)

There are other ways, such as using `createDocumentFragment`, but this second method is almost certainly the way for you to go.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about the `+= name;` part. This really helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create input box every time user enter text in prompt

```
function addInput(){
    var text = prompt("");
    var input = document.createElement('input');
    input.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(input);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The super short way:

```
function renderInput(){
    document.getElementById("latest").innerHTML += prompt("What is your name?") + "<br />";
}
```

Using your example:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("latest").innerHTML += prompt("Enter some text:") + "<br />";
    }
</script>

<p>Latest text: <span id="latest"></span></p>
```